# How to test if json property is present during the build of a Flutter ListView

Tags: json, listview, dart, flutter, listviewitem

I'm beginner in Flutter and Dart.

I have a local JSON file, read it and I want to display the JSON Data in the ListView.
But in my JSON data I haven't always all the different properties.
So when I want to display a text, the value of the property is no existing because the property is not existing (In the case is the Property "description".

How could I solve it ?

Thank you in advance for your help

I tried ternary operator
I tried with the function containsKey

But maybe I did it wong ?

... json

```
[
  {
    "createdBy": "bddae0de-320c-41a9-a69b-75793758b7a7",
    "description": "Fhjifgsdsdsd",
    "endDateTime": "1477490400000",
    "hasPicture": "false",
    "isActive": "true",
    "isAdminActive": "true",
    "maxParticipants": "50",
    "startDateTime": "1476799200000",
    "title": "Song Church Story Telling",
    "type": "Music"
  },
  {
    "createdBy": "-KHzgxS6KBqu1rNmJzpT",
    "endDateTime": "1476378000000",
    "hasPicture": "false",
    "isActive": "true",
    "isAdminActive": "true",
    "startDateTime":"1476205200000",
    "title": "Test greg T",
    "titleDate": "Tuesday, 11 Oct 8:00 PM",
    "type": "Games"
  }
]
```

...

... flutter

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Load local JSON file"),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            // Use future builder and DefaultAssetBundle to load the local JSON file
            child: new FutureBuilder(
                future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('assets/data/ckevents_data.json'),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  // Decode the JSON
                  var newData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                  return new ListView.builder(
                    // Build the ListView
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new Card(
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text("Title: " + newData[index]['title'],
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blue)),
                            new Text(
                                "Description: " +
                                        ((newData[index].containsKey('description')) ? ('') : (newData[index]['description'])),
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.pink)),
                            new Text("Categorie: " + newData[index]['type'],
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.red)),
                            new Text(
                                "Date: " +
                                    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                            newData[index]['startDateTime'])
                                        .add(Duration(days: 700))
                                        .toString(),
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black))
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: newData == null ? 0 : newData.length,
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the null coalesce operator like so:

```dart
 new Text("Description: " + newData[index]['description'] ?? ''),
```

This will print the description if it exists, and an empty string if it doesn't.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your fast reüply. I tried already this solution. Maybe I do somthing wrong. With your solution I have still an error, only the first Item is displayed and after I have message on the phone : Invalid Argumet(s)

And in VSCode, I have theerror at same line as before. 

Merci Julien, other ideas from were is coming my issue ?

Comment: see my reply upper

Comment: as far as I see, in your code, you use the ternary `?` operator. In this answer, I tell you to use the null coalesce operator `??` it's different. Have you tries it too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way 
1. make model class for your response json like this way..

```
class UserData {
final int albumId;
final int id;
final String title;
final String url;
final String thumbnailUrl;

UserData({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return new UserData(
    albumId: json['albumId'],
    id: json['id'],
    title: json['title'],
    url: json['url'],
    thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl']);
}
}
```

now make list object ..

```
  List<UserData> list = List();
```

then add data..

```
list = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
      .map((data) => UserData.fromJson(data))
      .toList();
```

read json file like this way..

```
class _ApiCallScreenState extends State<ApiCallScreen> {
@override
void initState() {
String data = await  DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
 list = (json.decode(data) as List)
  .map((data) => UserData.fromJson(data))
  .toList();
super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, I tried already a solution like this, my class is already existing and it should be the next step to use it, but when I tried to use it I had first problem to create my list from a json file in assets. No idea why, maybe not right function to read the file and create the list ? It why I tried first a simplified approach and I get the issue with missing properties with no way to test it and skip it if not present.

Comment: Thank you for the place where I have to put it, but which function I have to use to read a File.
In your solution data could be a file ? or do I have to use a function like:

String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data/ckevents_data.json"); and then do like you do for the list ?